# HttpsURLConnection of java get insufficient data written error

Tags: java, spring, httpsurlconnection

I want to call http url and get some json payload using `Httpsurlconnection` with post method and sending body json and some header parameter. following is my code and i get error insufficient data written

**JAVA**

```
public Map<String, Object> makeHttpPostRequestCall(String httpURL, Map<String, Object> apiParamsMap) {
    logger.info("call request call");
    String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String encodedNonce = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(nonce.getBytes());
    String token = UtilService.getString(apiParamsMap, RyderConnectConstants.PRIMARY_KEY);
    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    body.put("startDateTime", "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z");
    body.put("endDateTime", "2017-07-22T17:32:28Z");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    URL url;
    Map<String, Object> feedPaylaod = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(httpURL);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;

        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("nonce", encodedNonce);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", token);

        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Body", body.toString());
        logger.info("pp1");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");


        httpConn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(body.toString().length());
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        logger.info("pp");

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
        out.write(body.toString());
        out.close();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
        logger.info("reader"+reader);
        String line = null;
        StringWriter out =  new StringWriter(connection.getContentLength() > 0 ? connection.getContentLength() : 20480);
        logger.info("out"+out);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        String response = out.toString();
        feedPaylaod = stringToMap(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        feedPaylaod = Maps.newHashMap();
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return feedPaylaod;
}
```